# Can running total be achieved in SSIS, without any Hand coding?

Tags: ssis, etl, cumulative-sum

I have scenario where I have to do running total, I could achieve this by pure T-SQL or Script Task. But i want to avoid hand coding, and use ETL tools features. Is it possible and how.

I have table balances

```
SELECT '00000001' AS [AccountNo], CONVERT(date,'20080828') AS [Date],10 AS [DailyMovement]
INTO   balances
UNION  ALL
SELECT '00000001' AS [AccountNo], CONVERT(date,'20080829') AS [Date],5 AS [DailyMovement]
UNION  ALL
SELECT '00000001' AS [AccountNo], CONVERT(date,'20080830') AS [Date],7 AS [DailyMovement]
UNION  ALL
SELECT '00000002' AS [AccountNo], CONVERT(date,'20080828') AS [Date],8 AS [DailyMovement]
UNION  ALL
SELECT '00000002' AS [AccountNo], CONVERT(date,'20080829') AS [Date],6 AS [DailyMovement]
```

I get ruuning total like this.

```
SELECT b1.[AccountNo]
,      b1.[Date]
,      b1.[DailyMovement]
,      SUM(b2.[DailyMovement]) AS [RunningTotal]
FROM   balances b1
INNER  JOIN balances b2 ON  b1.[AccountNo] = b2.[AccountNo]
                           AND b1.[Date] >= b2.[Date]
GROUP  BY b1.[AccountNo],b1.[Date],b1.[DailyMovement];
```

want to do this in SSIS without hand coding

Comment: what do you understand by running total? can you give an example?

Comment: @Diego edited question to explain my scenario.

Comment: ok got it, but where do you want to insert this information? do you need only the totals or do you need something from the balances table?

Comment: only total, i can dump the result in file or anything...

Answer (score 3):

did you try adding the query

```
SELECT b1.[AccountNo]
,      b1.[Date]
,      b1.[DailyMovement]
,      SUM(b2.[DailyMovement]) AS [RunningTotal]
FROM   balances b1
INNER  JOIN balances b2 ON  b1.[AccountNo] = b2.[AccountNo]
                           AND b1.[Date] >= b2.[Date]
GROUP  BY b1.[AccountNo],b1.[Date],b1.[DailyMovement];
```

to an oledbsource to use it as Source and then directly pointing it to an oledbdestination?

Comment: sometimes the best answer is to use the part of the toolset that works best for a problem...  either t-sql or script tasks work well for this, and built-in components do not.  Use the proper tool from your toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  Not without hand coding something.  Best option for running totals that I have found is this article by Jeff Moden at [SQLServerCentral](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/)